# C error C2660: 'Menu' : function does not take 3 arguments

Tags: c

I am new to programming and do not understand this error.

I have the same arguments in the Menu () function and when I call the same function in the menu_principal () function.
In function menu_principal(), I want execute the switch-case statement by the function Menu() with 'option' variable.

Can you help please?

```
int main()
{
    void menu_principal();
    return 0;

}

void menu_principal()
{

    bool stop = true;
    int option;

    const char *title = "MENU PRINCIPAL";
    const char *options_menu[] = { "ARTIGOS", "CLIENTES", "ORCAMENTOS", "SAIR" };
    int n_options = 4; 

    do
    {
        option = Menu(title, options_menu, n_options);

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            Menu_Item();
            break;
        case 2:
            Menu_Client();
            break;
        case 3:
            Menu_Billing();
            break;
        case 4:

            stop = false;
            break;

        }
    } while (stop);

}



int Menu(const char *title1, const char *options_menu1[], int n_options1)
{

    int OptionSelected= 1;
    int key;
    bool stop = true;

    do
    {
        system("cls");

        gotoxy(5, 3 + OptionSelected); printf(">>"); 

        gotoxy(15, 2); printf("%s", title1);


        for (int i = 0; i < n_options1; i++)
        {
            gotoxy(10, 4 + i); 
            printf("%s ", options_menu1[i]);
        }

        do
        {
            key = _getch();
        } while (key != KEY_UP && key != KEY_DOWN && key != KEY_ENTER );


        switch (key)
        {

        case KEY_UP:

            OptionSelected--;

            if (OptionSelected < 1)
            {
                OptionSelected = n_options1;
            }
            break;

        case KEY_DOWN:
            OptionSelected--;
            if (OptionSelected > n_options1)
            {
                OptionSelected = 1;
            }
            break;

        case KEY_ENTER:
            stop = false;
            break;
        }

    } while (stop);


    return OptionSelected;


}
```

Comment: If you want to call the `menu_principal` function in `main`, you d not need the `void`, just `menu_prinipal();`.

Comment: `void menu_principal();` merely tells the compiler that somewhere exists a function called `menu_principal` that takes no arguments and returns nothing. This construct doesn't _call_ the function, so, your entire program does effectively nothing.

Comment: Forward declaration of the `Menu` function might help. What I mean by this is to put this `int Menu(const char *title1, const char *options_menu1[], int n_options1);` above `main`. Not IN main, but above it. Can you confirm that you have done this?

Comment: @bejado remove `void` but error keep up

Comment: @smac89 SOLVED   I put  `int Menu();` above `main` but i don t pass the arguments. So, i put `int Menu(const char *title1, const char *options_menu1[], int n_options1);` and work fine. Thanks

Comment: @AndréFerreira, excellent! Looks like someone else already answered the question, so accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler reads your program top to bottom, so it sees:

```
option = Menu(title, options_menu, n_options);
```

On this line, you call a previously unknown function, `Menu`.
Because the function is unknown, the compiler assumes it will be `int Menu(void)`.  (takes no parameters, returns an `int`).

That assumption is obviously different from how Menu eventually gets declared.

To fix this, declare the function properly near the top of your file:

```
int Menu(const char *title1, const char *options_menu1[], int n_options1);
```

Then, when the compiler encounters your function-call, it will not assume a declaration, it will use the declaration you already provided (takes 3 parameters, and returns an `int`)

Comment: If there was no prototype, the compiler should *not* assume `void Menu(void)`... but from comments above it looks like he may have had `int Menu();` as a prototype.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't assume an implicit declaration?  C compilers back to the earliest ones had implicit declarations of functions.  They generally all now create Warnings on implicit declarations, but they still allow it.

Comment: If it assumes an implicit declaration, it should assume return type is `int` and guess the parameter types based on the arguments passed... not assume `void` return and no parameters.  Though for newer versions of the standard, a declaration is supposed to be required before use...